# Function acting as a shortcut to object's methods

Tags: javascript, python, interfaces, proxy

I was reading Python's [requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/api.py#L56) library's code to find out how it works. Since this library has a simple usage interface, it creates a more complex object beyond. For instance:

```
requests.get(...)
```

Is a shortcut to something like:

```
s = Session()
r = s.request("get", ...)
return r
```

I do like this approach but I'd like to know whether it is a well-known design pattern or not. It's important to say that we are able to use Session class (it isn't a private/internal class).

We can see a similar (little bit different I guess) technique in Javascript.

```
Date.now = function () { return new Date().getTime ....
```

Is there a name to this approach? After spending some minutes looking for it, I wasn't able to find a suitable explanation. Should I consider it as a [Proxy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) or a [Facade](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)?

Comment: The link to the Requests library doesn't seem to have the code you cited. Could you provide a more specific reference? The function defined on lines 59-70 is just a wrapper.

Comment: I've just updated the link. This behavior could be found at line 56, inside a context manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is many way to classify the idiom.

Wrapper of course, but it can lead to many patterns associate with it.

book [**Implementation Patterns**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321413091) mentions some patterns:

`LIBRARY CLASS` in Chapter 5:

> Where do you put functionality that doesn’t fit into any object? One solution is to create static methods on an otherwise-empty class. **No one is expected to ever create instances of this class.** It is just there as a holder for the functions in the library.

also `METHOD OBJECT` in Chapter 7:

> This is one of my favorite patterns, probably because I use it so infrequently but the results are spectacular when I do. Creating method object can help you turn a tangled mass of code packed into an impossible method into readable, clear code **that gradually reveals details to readers**. This is a pattern I apply after I have some code working, and the more complex the method the better.

Also I think it is a simple Adapter/Facade pattern as @Joel Harmon already mention.

I think The purpose of the idiom in your case:

1. Requests library:

   > 1. reveals details to readers/users
   > 2. keep api easy to use
   > 3. Layers Architecture, High Level Low Level divide, low level can change, high level api won't
2. Date.now:

   I look on https://developer.mozilla.org

> #### Description
>
> Because now() is a static method of Date, you always use it as Date.now().
>
> #### Polyfill
>
> This method was standardized in ECMA-262 5th edition. Engines which have not been updated to support this **method can work around the absence of this method using the following shim**:

```
if (!Date.now) {
  Date.now = function now() {
    return new Date().getTime();
  };
}
```

> 1. "using the following shim" so it is a adapter
> 2. "static method of Date", yes `LIBRARY CLASS` as the book [**Implementation Patterns**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321413091) said.

Answer (score 1):

This idiom is simply a **wrapper**.

The function you call provides a somewhat cleaner interface to another function that would otherwise appear more awkward to use. I called it an idiom, rather than a pattern, because it's three lines of code. As I understand it, this is used extensively in Functional Programming as well as any language that supports functions as first class objects.

If, however, you're looking for a term referring to using wrappers to create a new interface for existing functionality, I'd consider that the **Adapter pattern**. If it was working with more than one backing object (in this case, the session.request function), it would be the **Facade pattern**.